# Assistance Creating Bag of Words Model

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tibble

Disclaimer: this is part of a homework assignment.

I have a set of tweets, and I need to create a classifier to try and predict their sentiments. I will do this by creating a Bag of Words model and applying a radial SVM kernel function to the data.

Here is the original data to give you an idea:

```
> original_tweets
# A tibble: 2,385 x 3
   tweet_id sentiment text                                                                                                                      
      <int> <chr>     <chr>                                                                                                                     
 1        1 positive  @TylerSkewes: It is almost 2014. Where are the self-driving cars so we don't have to worry about a DD tonight. Forreal tho
 2        2 positive  @WIRED: BMW builds a self-driving car -- that drifts I love this technology. Drive me to work baby!
 3        3 positive  Google better hurry up with that driverless car. Watching grandma do an 8 point turn to get in a parking spot is horrific.
 4        4 positive  I just waved thank you to this lady that let me merge on the highway and she gave me the finger. Need my self driving car.
 5        5 positive  I might be the only person who starts #cheering in their car when they see a @google car :) #happiness #feelslikeChristmas
 6        6 positive  I want the driverless car, and BAD. Seriously I would be happy if tomorrow morning there were no drivers behind the wheel.
 7        7 positive  I'm over here writing a 2000 word essay while *****s at Google are on driverless cars making ground breaking shit. Damn. _
 8        8 positive  Is it crazy to think that self driving cars will be the biggest innovation of the last few decades? 
 9        9 positive  Its very nice!RT @cdixon: It's awesome that Google is investing in futuristic stuff like AR glasses and self-driving cars.
10       10 positive  Look closely you will see the reflection of a google car !!!! Screen shot from google maps !!!!!
# ... with 2,375 more rows
>
```

I have edited a few terms slightly because they have URLs in them, but you get the idea.

I have formatted the data into a tidy format, and computed each terms TF-IDF scores. For my feature space, I am taking the top 1000 highest IDF scored terms.

Here is an example of my data:

```
> feature_space
# A tibble: 3,000 x 7
   tweet_id sentiment word                   n     tf   idf tf_idf
      <int> <chr>     <chr>              <int>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1        1 positive  forreal                1 0.0435  7.78  0.338
 2        2 positive  drifts                 1 0.0476  7.78  0.370
 3        2 positive  rprjtelkg6             1 0.0476  7.78  0.370
 4        5 positive  cheering               1 0.0455  7.78  0.353
 5        5 positive  feelslikechristmas     1 0.0455  7.78  0.353
 6        7 positive  2000                   1 0.0476  7.78  0.370
 7        7 positive  *****s                 1 0.0476  7.78  0.370
 8        8 positive  decades                1 0.0417  7.78  0.324
 9        8 positive  vltlymug89             1 0.0417  7.78  0.324
10        9 positive  ar                     1 0.0476  7.78  0.370
# ... with 2,990 more rows
```

I would like to create a Bag of Words model using their TF-IDF scores to create a sentiment classifier. For this model, I know that I need to set up my data frame such that each tweet is a row, and a column for each possible TF-IDF term weight in my feature space.

I am having a hard time figuring out how best to mutate a tibble or data frame to get the data into this format. I have tried various combinations of mutate() and join() but it's never quite the way I would like it.

How can I add 3000 or more columns quickly to a dataframe or tibble based on a set of feature words, and apply their TF-IDF values to fill in this sparse data structure? I don't necessarily need a direct code answer, but a step in the right direction on how to accomplish this in R would be of great help to me.

UPDATE: I now have an empty tibble for my bag of words, I just need to fill in the non-zero TF-DF values in the data. Here it is:

```
    > bag_of_words
# A tibble: 2,385 x 3,002
   tweet_id sentiment forreal drifts rprjtelkg6 cheering feelslikechristmas `2000` *****s decades vltlymug89    ar closely reflection zg7hvvfgpn
      <int> <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>              <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1        1 positive        0      0          0        0                  0      0      0       0          0     0       0          0          0
 2        2 positive        0      0          0        0                  0      0      0       0          0     0       0          0          0
 3        3 positive        0      0          0        0                  0      0      0       0          0     0       0          0          0
 4        4 positive        0      0          0        0                  0      0      0       0          0     0       0          0          0
 5        5 positive        0      0          0        0                  0      0      0       0          0     0       0          0          0
 6        6 positive        0      0          0        0                  0      0      0       0          0     0       0          0          0
 7        7 positive        0      0          0        0                  0      0      0       0          0     0       0          0          0
 8        8 positive        0      0          0        0                  0      0      0       0          0     0       0          0          0
 9        9 positive        0      0          0        0                  0      0      0       0          0     0       0          0          0
10       10 positive        0      0          0        0                  0      0      0       0          0     0       0          0          0
# ... with 2,375 more rows, and 2,987 more variables
```

Comment: Apologies if my example data is offensive, I will censor the expletives...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I think I have a solution. I would definitely be curious how to make this without for loops though, I am still not super comfortable with the apply() style of coding.

Here's what I came up with:

```
#create bag of words model
#get tweet_id and sentiment
bag_of_words <- original_tweets %>%
  select(-one_of('text'))

#get words from feature space
feature_words <- feature_space$word

#generate empty columns
for(i in feature_words)
  bag_of_words[,i] <- 0

#fill in columns with values from feature space
for(i in 1:length(feature_words)) {
  word <- feature_space[i,]$word
  tweet <- feature_space[i,]$tweet_id
  score <- feature_space[i,]$tf_idf
  bag_of_words[tweet,word] <- score
}
```

Checking output, looks good:

```
> bag_of_words
# A tibble: 2,385 x 3,002
   tweet_id sentiment forreal drifts rprjtelkg6 cheering feelslikechristmas `2000` *****s decades vltlymug89    ar closely reflection zg7hvvfgpn
      <int> <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>              <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1        1 positive    0.338  0          0        0                  0      0      0       0          0     0       0          0          0    
 2        2 positive    0      0.370      0.370    0                  0      0      0       0          0     0       0          0          0    
 3        3 positive    0      0          0        0                  0      0      0       0          0     0       0          0          0    
 4        4 positive    0      0          0        0                  0      0      0       0          0     0       0          0          0    
 5        5 positive    0      0          0        0.353              0.353  0      0       0          0     0       0          0          0    
 6        6 positive    0      0          0        0                  0      0      0       0          0     0       0          0          0    
 7        7 positive    0      0          0        0                  0      0.370  0.370   0          0     0       0          0          0    
 8        8 positive    0      0          0        0                  0      0      0       0.324      0.324 0       0          0          0    
 9        9 positive    0      0          0        0                  0      0      0       0          0     0.370   0          0          0    
10       10 positive    0      0          0        0                  0      0      0       0          0     0       0.370      0.370      0.370
# ... with 2,375 more rows, and 2,987 more variables
```

In retrospect I was probably making this harder on myself than I needed to, but I would definitely like seeing any more efficient ways to do this seasoned R vets could come up with. Cheers.

Comment: Haven't done any work on this, but you appear to be under the incorrect impression that for loops are less efficient than using `lapply` or `sapply`. This is a claim still made by uninformed persons who have not been keeping up with the changes in R. It has not been true now for over ten years. The key issue if in the algorithm being used. Yours appears to be quite inefficient, but the question doesn't have a [MCVE] so I can't attempt a demonstration how to use vectorized functions or maybe `mapply` to accomplish what you are doing with your `for`-loop.